# Why does group homology do not depend on the coefficient ring?

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

In Joseph J. Rotman's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*. It is stated (exercise 9.22, ii) that for a commutative ring $k$ and a group $G$, one has, for every integer $n$ and left $kG$ module $A$: $$
\mathrm{Tor}_n^{kG}(k,A) \simeq \mathrm{Tor}_n^{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z}, A)
$$

This implies that group homology does not depend on the coefficient ring we chose. However, I am stuck with proving this isomorphism. By tensoring (over $\mathbb{Z}$) with the ring $k$ a $\mathbb{Z}G$-module, one can obtain a $kG$-module. So I think the idea is to tensor with $k$ a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}G$ to obtain something over $kG$. However, there are several points I don't understand:

- Why will this construction still yield a projective resolution?
- Why taking the homology of the coinvariants of this resolution will yield isomorphic homology groups despite the operations that were made, i.e the tensoring by $k$, and taking the coinvariants of a $kG$ module instead of the coinvariants of a $\mathbb{Z}G$ module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a free resolution $P_\bullet$ of $\mathbb Z$ (as $\mathbb ZG$-module). Note that as $\mathbb Z$-modules, this resolution splits (because $\mathbb Z$ is free over itself); hence applying $kG\otimes_{\mathbb ZG} - \cong k\otimes_\mathbb Z -$ leaves it exact. It is also clearly still free  (as $kG$-modules), hence $P_\bullet\otimes_{\mathbb ZG} kG$ is a free resolution of $k$.

Moreover, we have an isomorphism of chain complexes $P_\bullet\otimes_{\mathbb ZG}kG \otimes_{kG} A\cong P_\bullet\otimes_{\mathbb ZG} A$. Taking homology yields the claim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought I understood on first reading, but thinking back I am not fure I fully understand why applying $k \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} -$ leaves the sequence exact. I get that Z is free over itself. When you say the resolution split, do you mean each short sequence of the resolution is split?

Comment: I mean that there is a contracting chain homotopy for the resolution $P_\bullet\to \mathbb Z$. If we denote by $\hat P_\bullet$ the complete exact sequence (including the $\mathbb Z$ at the end), then there are maps (of $\mathbb Z$-modules) $h\colon \hat P_i\to \hat P_{i+1}$ such that $\mathrm{Id}=hd+dh$ (where $d$ is the differential). Applying $k\otimes_{\mathbb Z}-$ preserves the properties of such $h$ and it is clear that the existence of such a $h$ implies exactness of the complex (because for a chain $x$ we have $x=hdx+dhx=0+d(hx)$, hence $x$ is a boundary).

Comment: How do you obtain such a contracting homotopy? You inductively use that $\hat P_\bullet$ consists of projective $\mathbb Z$-modules. The very first $h\colon \mathbb Z=\hat P_0\to \hat P_1=P_1$ can be chosen to be any splitting of the surjection $P_1\to\mathbb Z$. That means that the s.e.s $0\to C_1\to P_1\to \mathbb Z\to 0$ splits, which makes $C_1$ a direct summand of $P_1$ (hence projective), hence you can define the next $h$ as the $P_1\to C_1\to P_2$ where the first map is a direct summand projection and the second is a lift of the surjection $P_2\to C_1$. Then you continue like that...